# How do I remove a recurring reminder on a Slack channel that I've not set up?

Tags: slack

Looking to remove a recurring reminder on a Slack channel. The reminder has not been set up by me so the /remind list command doesn't work (as I've not created the reminders).

Answer (score 26):

Actually, you can use `/remind list` in any channel to see all of the reminders (including those created other persons) and remove them.
You just need to use it in that channel with the reminder to remove.

Answer (score 0):

The '/remind list' doesn't work if aren't the user who set up the reminder for the Slack channel.  You should be able to kick the bot out of the channel and then recreate a new bot reminder if needed.